# Xamarin Forms Android Prism MasterDetail Hamburger Menu not working after open camera/gallery

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-camera, prism, master-detail, hamburger-menu

I have a Xamarin Forms/Prism App with a MasterDetail Page. In a couple of the detail pages I have buttons to open the camera/gallery using CrossMedia plugin. I'm noticing that when the Camera/Gallery is closed (either cancelled or after photo taken/selected) in ANDROID the Hamburger Menu icon ceases to open the Master Menu. I'm still able to swipe the menu in from the left though but the Hamburger button does nothing.

I've created a simple repo app with the same functionality and the hamburger menu works fine after opening the camera so it is something specific to my app, but I have no clue how to figure out the cause.

Works as expected on iOS.

Vague I know, but if anyone could offer any direction on how to diagnose that would be MUCH appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I've identified the cause if anyone else comes across this. I had the following in OnResume:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    base.OnResume();
}
```

Moving back in to OnCreate has solved.